# Replace characters after a defined pattern with regexp_replace in oracle

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I want to replace single characters in a string with the function regexp_replace in oracle. The replacement in the string should start behind a defined pattern.

**Example:**

In the String "Heyho || HeyheyHo" i would replace all the "y" characters behind the pattern "||" with the character "i". The characters occuring before the pattern should be ignored.

**String:**

```
Heyho || HeyheyHo
```

String after replacement:

```
Heyho || HeiheiHo
```

Surely quite easy for you?

Comment: There is always one `||` in string? or may be multiple times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using regexp_replace. The 4th argument is the starting position. After some thought, I decided not to skip the '+2'.  Don't be lazy and waste cycles testing characters you know are not the target character.

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'Heyho || HeyheyHo' from dual
   )
   select str before,
          regexp_replace(str, 'y', 'i', instr(str, '||')+2) after
   from tbl;

BEFORE            AFTER
----------------- -----------------
Heyho || HeyheyHo Heyho || HeiheiHo

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you Gary. This solution is what i basically wanted, i better study the syntax next time.

Comment: I'm curious why you would not select Aleksej's proven faster method?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this; you can use `INSTR`, `SUBSTR` and `REPLACE` to get your need:

```
with test(s) as (
        select 'Heyho || HeyheyHo' from dual
    )
    /* the query */
    select s as input,
           substr(s, 1, instr(s, '||')+1) || 
           replace( substr(s, instr(s, '||')+2), 'y', 'i') as result
    from test
```

gives:

```
INPUT             RESULT
----------------- --------------------
Heyho || HeyheyHo Heyho || HeiheiHo
```

How it works:

```
select s as input,
       substr(s, 1, instr(s, '||')+1) beforeDelimiter,
       substr(s, instr(s, '||')+2)   afterDelimiter,
       replace( substr(s, instr(s, '||')+2), 'y', 'i') afterDelimiterEdited,
       substr(s, 1, instr(s, '||')+1) || 
       replace( substr(s, instr(s, '||')+2), 'y', 'i') as result
from test
```

gives:

```
INPUT             BEFOREDELI AFTERDELIM AFTERDELIM RESULT
----------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
Heyho || HeyheyHo Heyho ||    HeyheyHo   HeiheiHo  Heyho || HeiheiHo
```

If more than one `||` occurs in the string, the `replace` will modify the characters after the first occurence.

According to Mathguy's comment, I can not say that this solution is faster than a regexp one.

A solution with regexp could be:

```
select regexp_replace(s, 'y', 'i', instr(s, '||') ) as result
```

Here is a small performance test on 2 tables created the same way with the same data (5 millions rows):

```
SQL> create table testA3(s) as
  2  select regexp_replace(s, 'y', 'i', instr(s, '||') ) as result
  3  from testA;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:30.75
SQL> create table testB3(s) as
  2  select substr(s, 1, instr(s, '||')+1) ||
  3             replace( substr(s, instr(s, '||')+2), 'y', 'i') as result
  4  from testB;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:14.82
```

The standard approach seems faster here; the same test with 3M rows took 18 seconds for the regexp approach and 7 seconds for the standard one.

The test is of course not exhaustive and the results may change depending on many things, but it is a point to consider the standard way a good alterative to regexp even in this case, where many standard operations are needed to get the same result of a regexp.

Here is the complete test for 3M rows; I did a `CREATE` and 2 `INSERT`s to avoid memory issues with `CONNECT BY` with a very high level.

Also, between the 3M and the 5M rows tests, I dropped the tables and created them again, to be sure that cache could not affect the results.

```
SQL> create table testA(s) as
  2  select 'Heyho || HeyheyHo' || level || 'HeyheyHo'
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 1000000;

Table created.

SQL> create table testB(s) as
  2  select 'Heyho || HeyheyHo' || level || 'HeyheyHo'
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 1000000;

Table created.

SQL> insert into testB(s)
  2  select 'Heyho || HeyheyHo' || to_char(level + 1000000) || 'HeyheyHo'
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 1000000;

1000000 rows created.

SQL> insert into testA(s)
  2  select 'Heyho || HeyheyHo' || to_char(level + 1000000)  || 'HeyheyHo'
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 1000000;

1000000 rows created.

SQL> insert into testB(s)
  2  select 'Heyho || HeyheyHo' || to_char(level + 2000000)  || 'HeyheyHo'
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 1000000;

1000000 rows created.

SQL> insert into testA(s)
  2  select 'Heyho || HeyheyHo' || to_char(level + 2000000)  || 'HeyheyHo'
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 1000000;

1000000 rows created.

SQL> select count(1), count(distinct s) from testA;

  COUNT(1) COUNT(DISTINCTS)
---------- ----------------
   3000000          3000000

SQL> select count(1), count(distinct s) from testB;

  COUNT(1) COUNT(DISTINCTS)
---------- ----------------
   3000000          3000000

SQL> set timing on
SQL> create table testA2(s) as
  2  select regexp_replace(s, 'y', 'i', instr(s, '||')+2 ) as result
  3  from testA;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:17.66
SQL> create table testB2(s) as
  2  select substr(s, 1, instr(s, '||')+1) ||
  3             replace( substr(s, instr(s, '||')+2), 'y', 'i') as result
  4  from testB;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:06.96
SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast and successful reply, Aleksej

Comment: In most cases, using standard (non-reg-exp) functions results in faster execution. However, in this example I count six string functions per row: two `instr`, two `substr`, a `replace` and a concatenation. In this case, the solution using regular expressions may be faster - is uses one `instr` and one `regexp_replace`. Standard functions are faster, but not five times faster.

Comment: @mathguy I honestly underrated the fact that so many standard functions could lead to a slower solution. I just did (and posted) a small test to check how it goes and it seems that the standard approach is still faster than the regexp one. It's only a single test on a single instance, but ...

Comment: Neat! Thank you for posting the performance comparison. It would help (if it's not too much trouble) if you posted the statements to create the test table, too. Anyway, upvoted for the extra work. (OR... wait... by the same data, do you mean you copied the same input string 5 million times?)

Comment: @mathguy Right doubt; I created the tables with 3M different rows.Just posted the complete test for the 3M rows

Comment: I hate to be nit-picky, but the regex version test should have the starting point in the string as `instr(s, '||')+2` else it's comparing 10 million more characters than the non-regexp version of the test. Either way, thanks for doing the comparison, interesting.

Comment: @Gary_W You're right, I don't know where I lost the +2.... However, just tried again the 3M rows test and posted the result. The execution times are very similar to the previous ones.

Comment: @Aleksej I suspected it may not make a difference but was curious to know.  Thanks for retesting.